# android gradle custom configuration share output between modules

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have two modules on my app, `app1` and `app2`, the `app1` should put `app2`'s apk into the `assets` directory. I follow [this document](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_cross_project_output_sharing.html) create custom configuration and artifact.

Below is my script inside `app2`

```
configurations {
    apkFile {
        canBeConsumed = true
        canBeResolved = false
    }
}

def makeApkFile = tasks.register("makeApkFile", Copy) {
    dependsOn(tasks.getByName("assembleRelease"))
    from "${buildDir}/outputs/apk/release/"
    into "${buildDir}/apkFile"
    include "*.apk"
//    outputs.files(new File("${buildDir}/outputs/apk/release/"))
}

artifacts {
    apkFile(makeApkFile)
}
```

And on `app1`

```
android {
    sourceSets.main.assets.srcDirs(new File(project.buildDir, "app2apk"))
}
androidComponents {
    def taskProvider = tasks.register('copyApk', Copy) {
        from configurations.getByName("apkFile")
        into "${buildDir}/app2apk"
    }
    onVariants(selector().all(), { variant ->
        afterEvaluate {
            tasks.getByName("merge${variant.name.capitalize()}Assets")
                    .dependsOn(taskProvider)
        }
    })
}
configurations {
    apkFile {
        canBeConsumed = false
        canBeResolved = true
    }
}
dependencies {
    apkFile(project("path": ":app2", "configuration": "apkFile"))
}
```

When I run the command line `gradle :app1:assembleRelease`, everything is ok, `app2`'s apk generated and copied to the directory.

But when I click `run` button on Android Studio, the `app2`'s apk never generated, I saw the logs as shown below:

```
> Task :app2:assembleRelease
> Task :app2:makeApkFile NO-SOURCE
```

It seems the `assembleRelease` executed successful but there is no apk file generated. Why this could happen? I think Android Studio's run button also execute `:app1:assembleRelease` task, why there is something different?